# Create a rar file with the help of unrar package

Tags: compression, rar

The unrar is package is installed in my Arch Linux. I want to create a rar file, so I tried to install rar package from Arch AUR, but the repo is currently unavailable. So, I wonder if it is possible to create a rar file with the help of 'unrar' package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create `rar` archive with `unrar`.  `unrar` can be only used to unpack rar files.

You need to have full `rar` binary to create a rar file on linux.